# How do I override the category delete methods in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need to run some SQL to clear some custom tables in Magento when a category is being deleted. With that in mind, I have been following the examples laid out here: [Magento - Overriding core files](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

I have entered this into my config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <category_api>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Category_Apis</category_api>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>                      
    </models>
</global>
```

I then created the file structure:

```
MyCompany
-> MyModule
  -> Model
    ->Catalog
      ->Category
        ->Api.php
```

In Api.php file I have the following:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Catalog_Category_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api
{
    public function delete($categoryId)
    {
        Mage::log('I have overidden deletion of: ' . $categoryId);

        return true;
    }

}
```

I am getting nothing come out in the system.log when using this setup so I assume I am doing something wrong.

**EDIT**:

Changing my XML to `<category> </category>` seems to make it include my files as I now get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\CategoryController.php on line 52
```

Do I need to do something special when overriding the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it not better to create an observer to catch the event `catalog_category_delete_after`. Using events is preferred to function overrides and is more flexible too. Since your delete procedure does not alter catalog_category deletion but adds more functionality to it, using events seems to be a better option

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if I should be doing that. Would you be able to mock up an example of using events or link a good explanation for it?

Comment: Actually I see a good resource on Magento's site: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: Using events worked a treat and now I have read up on them it makes much more sense to use them.